# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0) in EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have tried a lot of variation of this error but failed. That's why I am asking. I am getting this error,

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries

Here is my code,

```
        var page = .....;// page Construction
        var oldPage = pageRepository.GetPageByID(id);
        if (oldPage != null){
             page.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
             context.Entry(page).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else{
              page.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
              page.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
             context.Pages.Add(page);
        }
        pageRepository.Save();
```

Comment: It is not clear from your code which contexts are involved, what their life span is and what kind of object `page` is (esp. whether it contains more objects to be saved). What happens in `pageRepository.Save()`, with which context?

Comment: @GertArnold, Context is DbContext with Pages properties. Add is working. But getting error on update. When calling Save i get the above error. I think this is due to the fact that page.ID = 0. If I set page.ID = oldPage.ID then I am getting some else error.